# Can't pass multiple arguments to function in Python

Tags: python, function, discord.py, arguments, parameter-passing

It doesn't let me pass multiple arguments to my function. Python keeps thinking I'm still defining the first argument. The code:

```
async def find(ctx, user, parachannel):
    user = int(user)
    parachannel = int(parachannel)
    funchannel = bot.get_channel(parachannel)
    fun_guild = bot.get_guild(880108797820026881)
    memberuser = fun_guild.get_member(user)
    fun_calc = 0
    async for message in funchannel.history(limit=10):
        if message.author == memberuser:
            fun_calc = fun_calc + 1
    return fun_calc


gen_calc = find(user, 880123663318409277)
print(gen_calc)
```

Getting this error:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: find() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parachannel'

Full Traceback:

```
2021-09-16T11:40:52.403142+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in command analyze:
2021-09-16T11:40:52.404102+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-09-16T11:40:52.404120+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core .py", line 85, in wrapped
2021-09-16T11:40:52.404121+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
2021-09-16T11:40:52.404122+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "main.py", line 132, in analyze
2021-09-16T11:40:52.404123+00:00 app[worker.1]:     gen_calc = find(user, 880123663318409277)
2021-09-16T11:40:52.404142+00:00 app[worker.1]: TypeError: find() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parachannel'
2021-09-16T11:40:52.404151+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2021-09-16T11:40:52.404152+00:00 app[worker.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2021-09-16T11:40:52.404152+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2021-09-16T11:40:52.404154+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-09-16T11:40:52.404170+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
2021-09-16T11:40:52.404170+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
2021-09-16T11:40:52.404172+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
2021-09-16T11:40:52.404173+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
2021-09-16T11:40:52.404181+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
2021-09-16T11:40:52.404181+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
2021-09-16T11:40:52.404195+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: find() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parachannel'
```

Comment: Your function waits for 3 arguments.

You call your function passing only 2 arguments.

Comment: Ctx isn't an argument, it's an object (I think) @Gustavo Araújo

Comment: just delete 'ctx' and test @Mushtaq Mahar

Comment: @MushtaqMahar ctx is quite literally a parameter for your function. It's only passed automatically for **commands**, not for regular methods. If you're calling the function yourself, either pass `ctx` as an argument or remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function requires three arguments but you only pass two to it. So, naturally you see an error. You should give your parameters some default values. For example something like this:

```
async def find(ctx = None, user = "Mushtaq", parachannel = 0):
    user = int(user)
    parachannel = int(parachannel)
... and the rest of your code.
```

Comment: If the username is a string by default then `int(user)` is gonna raise a `ValueError` though. I know this is an example but still.

Answer (score 0):

`find(ctx, user, parachannel)` function requires 3 arguments: `ctx`, `user` and `parachannel`. But when you call the function you're only giving two arguments. `ctx = user` and `user = 880123663318409277`. You're missing the 3rd argument `parachannel`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not necessary to keep `ctx` as first argument, you can do

```py
async def find(user, parachannel, ctx = None):
    # You codes
    return fun_calc
```

Now you can call your function without `ctx` argument.

```py
gen_calc = find(user, 880123663318409277)
```